# MySQL - How do I inner join sorting the joined data

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm trying to write a report which will join a person, their work, and their hourly wage at the time of work. I cannot seem to figure out the best way to join the person's cost when the date is less than the date of the work.

Let's say a person cost $30 per hour at the start of the year then got a $10 raise o Feb 5 and another on Mar 1.

- 01/01/2010 $30.00 (per hour)
- 02/05/2010 $40.00
- 03/01/2010 $45.00

The person put in hours several days which span the rasies.

- 01/05/2010 10 hours (should be at $30/hr)
- 01/27/2010 5 hours (again at $30)
- 02/10/2010 10 hours (at $40/hr)
- 03/03/2010 5 hours (at $45/hr)

I'm trying to write one SQL statement which will pull the hours, the cost per hour, and the hours*cost. The cost is the hourly rate last entered into the system so the cost date is less than the work date, ordered by cost date limit 1.

```
SELECT person.id, person.name, work.hours, person_costs.value, 
       work.hours * person_costs.value AS value
  FROM person
  JOIN work ON person.id = work.person_id
  JOIN person_costs ON person.id = person_costs.person_id 
                   AND person_costs.date < work.date
 WHERE person.id = 1234
ORDER BY work.date ASC
```

The problem I'm having, the person_costs isn't ordered by date in descending order. It's pulling out "any" value (naturally sorted by record position) which matches the condition. How do I select the first person_cost value which is older than the work date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to change the person_costs table so that it records the price over a date interval (start and finish) rather the price after a change. As long as you don't create any overlapping intervals, the join will always fetch only one row per person/date.

If you can't change the table structure, you can create a view that achieves the same effect.

Comment: This solution will work the best for me as the query will be faster than a sub query (looping through millions of records nightly). Building the CRUD for the person_cost was more tricky with all of the edge cases, but it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my test schema:

```
Create Table person_cost
                    (
                    PersonId int not null
                    , Rate decimal(15,4) not null
                    , [date] datetime not null
                    , Constraint PK_person_cost Primary Key Clustered ( PersonId, [date] )
                    )
Insert person_cost(PersonId, Rate, [date]) Values(1,30,'2010-01-01')
Insert person_cost(PersonId, Rate, [date]) Values(1,40,'2010-02-05')
Insert person_cost(PersonId, Rate, [date]) Values(1,50,'2010-03-01')

Create Table Work
                (
                PersonId int not null
                , [Date] datetime not null
                , Hours int not null
                )

Insert Work(PersonId, [Date], Hours) Values(1, '2010-01-05', 10)
Insert Work(PersonId, [Date], Hours) Values(1, '2010-01-27', 5)
Insert Work(PersonId, [Date], Hours) Values(1, '2010-02-10', 10)
Insert Work(PersonId, [Date], Hours) Values(1, '2010-03-03', 5)
```

And my query:

```
Select Work.PersonId, Work.Hours, PayRanges.Rate
    , Work.Hours * PayRanges.Rate As Value
From Work
    Join    (
            Select pc1.PersonId, pc1.[date] As StartDate, Rate
                , Coalesce((Select Min(pc2.[date])
                    From person_cost As pc2
                    Where pc2.personId = pc1.personId 
                        And pc2.[date] > pc1.[date])
                    , '9999-12-31') As NextEffectiveDate
            From person_cost As pc1
            ) As PayRanges
        On Work.PersonId = PayRanges.PersonId
            And Work.[Date] >= PayRanges.StartDate
            And Work.[Date] < PayRanges.NextEffectiveDate
```

In essence, I calculated the end date of the effective pay rate. In my example, I excluded a join to the Person table, however that can easily be included to get Person data. Note that my calculation of the expiration date of a pay rate will be the day the next pay rate takes effect and thus I query for value strictly less than the expiration date.